# hyperref URL using BibTeX

Tags: bibtex, hyperref, natbib, urls

I am trying to `hyperref`an URL using class `scrartcl`, `Bibtex`, package `natbib` and bibliography style `authordate1`. The paper is characterised as `@article` in the `.bib`file and as the URL entry is not used in `@article` I inserted it into the entry `note`. This works all fine but I would like to be able to click onto the URL and be led to the place in the internet. How can this be done?
Furthermore, is it possible to hide the ugly URL behind a clickable hyperref, e.g. the DOI behind the journal abbreviation and the ADS (Astrophysics Data System) behind the paper pages?

.bib entry:

```
% This file was created with JabRef 2.10.
% Encoding: UTF8


@Article{Schwamb2010,
Title                    = {Properties of the Distant Kuiper Belt: Results from the Palomar Distant Solar System Survey},
Author                   = {(Megan E.) Schwamb and (Michael E.) Brown and (David L.) Rabinowitz and Darin Ragozzine},
Journal                  = {The Astrophysical Journal},
Year                     = {2010},

Month                    = {September},
Note                     = {{\url{http://adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/2010ApJ...720.1691S}}},
Number                   = {2},
Pages                    = {1691},
Volume                   = {720},

Doi                      = {http://dx.doi.org/10.1088/0004-637X/720/2/1691},
Timestamp                = {2014.09.21},
Url                      = {http://m.iopscience.iop.org/0004-637X/720/2/1691/pdf/0004-637X_720_2_1691.pdf}
}
```

Comment: Please post a representative bib entry. By the way, the name of the field should probably be `note`, not `notes`. Furthermore, it's too general to say that "there is no URL [field] in `@article`": Which fields are recognized by BibTeX is determined by the bibliography style in use -- here: `authordate2`. Other bibliography styles (e.g., `plainnat`) *do* provide code so that BibTeX can process fields named `url` in entries of type `@article`.

Comment: Isn't there a way around the 'makebst' and keep a bibliography style with an overall appearance of the references while just adding some more informations like URLs, DOI and hyperref these?

Comment: The bibliography style file is BibTeX's exclusive source of information on how each entry, and each field within a given entry, should be formatted. If you don't want to use a given style file, all you can do is to either edit it or switch to a different style file altogether. The style file `authordate1.bst` appears to be quite old, having been changed most recently in **March 1990** -- when the Web was still mostly a gleam in Tim Berners-Lee's eyes... Its venerable age (almost certainly) explains why the style file doesn't do anything with fields such as `url`, `doi`, and `eid`, right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You ask:

> This works all fine but I would like to be able to click onto the URL and be led to the place in the internet. How can this be done?

It looks like you have one too many pairs of curly braces encasing the contents of the `note` field. Instead of writing

```
Note = {{\url{http://adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/2010ApJ...720.1691S}}},
```

you should write

```
Note = {\url{http://adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/2010ApJ...720.1691S}},
```

[image]

Incidentally, why do you surround the first names and middle initials of the first three authors -- but not the first name of the fourth author -- with round parentheses?

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{natbib,url,hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks,allcolors=blue}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@Article{Schwamb2010,
Title                    = {Properties of the Distant Kuiper Belt: Results from the Palomar Distant Solar System Survey},
Author                   = {(Megan E.) Schwamb and (Michael E.) Brown and (David L.) Rabinowitz and Darin Ragozzine},
Journal                  = {The Astrophysical Journal},
Year                     = {2010},

Month                    = {September},
Note                     = {\url{http://adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/2010ApJ...720.1691S}},
Number                   = {2},
Pages                    = {1691},
Volume                   = {720},

Doi                      = {http://dx.doi.org/10.1088/0004-637X/720/2/1691},
Timestamp                = {2014.09.21},
Url                      = {http://m.iopscience.iop.org/0004-637X/720/2/1691/pdf/0004-637X_720_2_1691.pdf}
}
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\bibliographystyle{authordate1}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

---

You also asked:

> Furthermore, is it possible to hide the ugly URL behind a clickable hyperref, e.g. the DOI behind the journal abbreviation and the ADS (Astrophysics Data System) behind the paper pages?

This can also be done (though I'm not sure how advisable it is do so...). Just replace the original contents of the `journal` and `pages` fields with `{\href{...}{original content}`. E.g.,

```
Journal = {\href{http://dx.doi.org/10.1088/0004-637X/720/2/1691}{The Astrophysical Journal}},
```

and

```
Pages = {\href{http://adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/2010ApJ...720.1691S}{1691}},
```

Doing so will generate the following output:

[image]

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{natbib,url,hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks,allcolors=blue}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@Article{Schwamb2010,
Title                    = {Properties of the Distant Kuiper Belt: Results from the Palomar Distant Solar System Survey},
Author                   = {Megan E. Schwamb and Michael E. Brown and David L. Rabinowitz and Darin Ragozzine},
Journal                  = {\href{http://dx.doi.org/10.1088/0004-637X/720/2/1691}{The Astrophysical Journal}},
Year                     = {2010},
Month                    = {September},
Number                   = {2},
Pages                    = {\href{http://adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/2010ApJ...720.1691S}{1691}},
Volume                   = {720},
Timestamp                = {2014.09.21},
}
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\bibliographystyle{authordate1}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

Comment: :Good point with the round parentheses of the last author name.

Comment: Concerning the curly brackets around the URL - also good point -, they do not seem to have any effect in the final pdf or create any warning or error so far.

Comment: I produce the .bib file with an external programm called JabRef because this expectation: when you insert into your .tex-code the \begin{filescontents}...\end{filescontents} with 30 papers, does your .tex-code not become unpleasantly long and nasty? So what does \jobname.bib actually do and can't you do this external of the .tex-code?

Comment: @Lucas - The `filecontents` device is just to make the example fully self-contained. For a real example, you'd place the bib entries in a separate file (with extension `.bib`). You can name your bib file (almost) anything you want; e.g., if you'd name it `references.bib`, you'd issue the command `\bibliography{references}` instead of `\bibliography{\jobname}`.

Comment: Ah that's what the filecontent-command is for. Great clarification!

Answer (score 0):

Answer to the first question: how can an URL in a note-entry be clickable?
By using this command:

```
note={\url{http://...}}
```