# URL linebreaking after double slashes

Tags: bibtex, line-breaking, urls

I have some URL entries in my bibliography. In several of them, I noticed that a break after "http://" instead of after "http" would improve both layout and readability. This is how one entry looks like right now:
[image]

How can I enforce a break after "http://" instead?
Or, is ist possible to remove the "http://" altogether (only have it in the link?)

This is how the URL is provided:

```
howpublished = {\url{http://www.harrisgeospatial.com/ProductsandSolutions/GeospatialProducts/ENVI.aspx}},
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can prevent breaks after the colon:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\textwidth=0.5cm
\begin{document}
blbl \url{http://www}

\appto\UrlNoBreaks{\do\:}

blbl \url{http://www}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Removing the `http://` would be easy with biblatex/biber (but more difficult if the link should remain clickable). With bibtex you would imho have to patch `\url`.

Comment: Looks like for omitting the `http://`, `\href{}{}` can be used. http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/204454/hyperref-url-using-bibtex